# Test case fails for toThrow() matcher

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

I am new to unit testing in JS, learning `jest` framework. I have problem with simple `toThrow()` matcher that I test my throwing error function with.

I have written simple `foo()` function that only throws an Error and test it with `toThrow()` matcher.

`index.js`

```js
export const foo = () => {
  throw new Error('bar');
};
```

`index.test.js`

```js
import {foo} from './index';

test('foo', () => {
  expect(foo()).toThrow();
});
```

As far as I understand, as the function throws error in any case, the expected result checked by `toThrow()` should resolve to a passed test. However, when I run `yarn test` I get the following failure:

```
 FAIL  index.test.js
  ✕ foo (3ms)

  ● foo

    bar

      21 | 
      22 | export const foo = () => {
    > 23 |   throw new Error('bar');
         |         ^
      24 | };
      25 | 

      at foo (index.js:23:9)
      at Object.<anonymous> (index.test.js:13:10)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
```

Is there some error in my code or maybe my understanding of the `toThrow()` matcher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a function to `expect` when using [`toThrow`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tothrowerror).

In this case you can simply pass `foo`:

index.js

```js
export const foo = () => {
  throw new Error('bar');
};
```

index.test.js

```js
import { foo } from './index';

test('foo', () => {
  expect(foo).toThrow();  // Success!
});
```

---

If throwing depends on a parameter then you can pass an arrow function that calls your function:

index.js

```js
export const foo = bar => {
  if (bar > 0) throw new Error('bar > 0');
};
```

index.test.js

```js
import { foo } from './index';

test('foo', () => {
  expect(() => foo(0)).not.toThrow();  // Success!
  expect(() => foo(1)).toThrow();  // Success!
});
```

Comment: What if throwing an error depends on a value of a function's parameter? Say error is thrown when parameter bar is greater than 0.

Comment: I added an example that passes parameters @MrLoon